# Atomic actions - what is meant by reads and writes?

Tags: java, atomic

Its one thing I don't get about concurrency - threads and atomic-actions. According to docs.oracle these actions are specified as atomic:

- Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double).
- Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared volatile (including long and double variables).

But at the same time docs.oracle asserts that incrementing a variable is not an atomic action. I thought that this was a write:

```
 private int number;
 number++;
```

Obviously I do not understand what is meant with "reads" and "writes".

Could someone explain this and give an example of "reads" and "writes"?

*Edit: When doing this without synchronization the programs suffers from ´thread interference. SO I understand that its not atomic. But when I change another variable that belongs to an object that these threads share - there are NO interference whatsoever. 
The shared variable from this object is changed via a mutator.*

Comment: *"Obviously I do not understand what is meant with "reads" and "writes"."*.  You probably do.  But you probably did not consider what really happens when you increment a variable.

Comment: @Stephen C - yes I know some assembly and know that highlevel code involves several instruction - fetch execute .... put the variable in register A. Add 1 to register A. put it back to memory and so on

Comment: I think that you don't have to go that low. Even `number++` in high level has a read and a write.

`number++ // is the same as number = number + 1`

You have a read right of the equal sign, then you add, then you write the result back to variable `number`.

Answer (score 6):

In order to implement `number++`, the runtime needs to

1. Acquire the current value of `number` (a read).
2. Increment that value.
3. Write that new value back to `number` (a write).

If another thread starts from 1 when you're at 2 then the final value for `number` will be incorrect since that thread will still be reading the original value.

If 1, 2 and 3 are executed as an *atomic* operation (i.e. a thread cannot start 1 until you've finished 3) then all will be well.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `number++` involves a write, but it also involves a read.  An atomic operation is, by definition, a single operation that either succeeds completely or fails completely.  Since `number++` performs multiple independent operations, it is not atomic.  There are, however, APIs to increment a value atomically as a single operation.  At runtime, those APIs make use of specialized CPU instructions which are able to perform both a read and a write as a single unit of work.

A single read or write to a word-aligned, word-sized (or smaller) value is atomic, e.g.:

```
int x;
x = 5  // write 'x'
5 + x  // read 'x'
```

So you probably *do* understand what a read or write is; you probably didn't consider that the `++` operator performs both discretely.

> When doing this without synchronization the programs suffers from ´thread interference. SO I understand that its not atomic. But when I change another variable that belongs to an object that these threads share - there are NO interference whatsoever. The shared variable from this object is changed via a mutator.

If you are manipulating shared data without a synchronization mechanism or atomic operations, and you are not seeing data races, then you simply got lucky, or data races *are* occurring, and you aren't noticing.  It is difficult to say without seeing your actual code.

Comment: No - not luckysince I made montecarlo-simulations over this - 10000 samples. Theres no interference concerning the variable that belongs to the shared object.

Comment: @user2991252 - Ermm ... this kind of race condition can happen one in a million, or one in a billion times.  And the rate of occurrence can depend on system load, number of cores, Java release, and so on.  You got lucky ... relatively speaking.

Comment: Or he's updating the value in a such a way that there isn't a meaningful hazard.  Hard to say without seeing the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing a value and referencing a value is not the same thing as incrementing also does a sum: this breaks atomicity as there is more than a simple read or write.